# json output to table using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq, tabular

I am trying to convert json output to a table format using jq.

here is my input

```
{
   "eTag" : null,
   "id" : "providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/8000000/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query/7acd05b7-5aff-49df-b7db-4d7f111eecf1",
   "location" : null,
   "name" : "7acd05b7-5aff-49df-b7db-4d7f111eecf1",
   "properties" : {
      "columns" : [
         {
            "name" : "Cost",
            "type" : "Number"
         },
         {
            "name" : "UsageDate",
            "type" : "Number"
         },
         {
            "name" : "CostStatus",
            "type" : "String"
         },
         {
            "name" : "Currency",
            "type" : "String"
         }
      ],
      "nextLink" : null,
      "rows" : [
         
         [
            15.87,
            20230818,
            "Cost",
            "USD"
         ],
         [
            17.00,
            20230819,
            "Cost",
            "USD"
         ],
         [
            16.27,
            20230820,
            "Cost",
            "USD"
         ]
      ]
   },
   "type" : "Microsoft.CostManagement/query"
}
```

My desired output

```
Cost | UsageDate 
----------------
15.87  | 20230818 
17.00  | 20230818
16.27  | 20230818
```

I am trying with jq so far i have only got but not the desired output format. Can you please share jq filter query to get the desired output
`.properties | (.columns[].name, .rows[])`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strating point you can build on, especially wrt refining some visual aspects not entirely explicated in your question. Use `.columns[:2]` and `.rows[][:2]` if you only want the first two columns.

```bash
jq -r '.properties
  | (.columns | map(.name) | join(" | ") | ., gsub("."; "-"))
  , (.rows[] | join(" | "))
'
```

```
Cost | UsageDate | CostStatus | Currency
----------------------------------------
15.87 | 20230818 | Cost | USD
17 | 20230819 | Cost | USD
16.27 | 20230820 | Cost | USD
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0y0Y-eqCwcJ)